# Cant send a FB notification using FB.api()

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send a notification via FB.api() and everything I am doing fails. I have not added any permissions besides the default permissions, just in case that is the issue I am putting that out there. Now here is my code before I continue on

```
FB.api('/100008601850848/notifications', 'post', 
{
    access_token: APP_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    template: "This message should appear",
    href: REDIRECT_URL,
}, 
function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error)
    {
        console.log("Error" + response.error);
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("It worked");
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. And the error doesn't show. Its just [object Object] how can I post it?

Comment: you should not do that on the client. you need an app token, and the app token should only be used server side.

Comment: and please use a proper browser to debug. chrome dev tools show objects, for example.

Comment: You are getting `[object Object]` because you are forcing string concatenation in your console.log statement - don’t ever do that, log the object on its own, without concatenating it to anything else. `console.log("Error:", response.error)`